# How to infer type from datetime string in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, timestamp

I have a table for which I want to infer custom types for each column.  Given a string, I want to distinguish whether it is a date, a time or a timestamp.  For instance, for the given list:

```
input_list = [
    "4th Sep 2013",
    "95-04-04 23:33:05",
    "May 5th 1999",
    "03:00:00",
    "10-01-22",
    "12-12-25 05:48:01.0010"]
```

I want an output that tells me (a list of strings)

```
output_types = [
    "date",
    "timestamp",
    "date",
    "time",
    "date",
    "timestamp"]
```

I have tried using `datetime`, but since I can't be sure of the input format (especially for dates) it is hard to infer automatically the input type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [parsedatetime](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime) module seems to provide this functionality, in the `parsedatetime.Calendar.parse()` method. According to the documentation:

> If the datetimeString is parsed and date/time value found then the second item of the returned tuple will be a flag to let you know what kind of struct_time value is being returned:
>
> ```
> 0 = not parsed at all
> 1 = parsed as a date
> 2 = parsed as a time
> 3 = parsed as a datetime
> ```

I don't know if it supports every date/time format that you've given in the examples.

Comment: Works for all of the formats I have suggested.  We're anticipating some pretty messy data, but this is a great start.

Answer (score -1):

Python supports posix from an OS level. You can use posix to distinguish between the different string types.

You can find more relevant details here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/posix.html